# Way of structure memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

```
struct Books {
   char  title[50];
};

int main( ) {

   struct Books Book1;       
   struct Books Book2;      

   strcpy( Book1.title, "C Programming");

   strcpy( Book2.title, "Telecom Billing");

   printf( "Book 2 title : %s\n", Book2.title);

   printf( "Book 1 title : %s\n", Book1.title);
  }
```

Here, everything got executed properly but I want to ask that how 'struct' is allocating memory for 'book2' without using any memory allocation function or any pointer?

Comment: Just like it's allocating for book1. Why are you asking specifically for book2?

Comment: The compiler allocates memory for you, somewhere. Unless you want to know how compilers work internally there is really nothing more to say.

Comment: In the same way that `int int2;` does.

Comment: When the concept of dynamic memory allocation came in 'struct' while learning about the linked list data structure, I got confused about the memory allocation here in normal 'struct'  program. So, I meant to ask that after allocating memory for 'Book1' , how is it allocating memory for 'Book2' ? @Sanjay-sopho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Book1` and `Book2` are *automatic* variables. They are automatically allocated once declared and automatically deallocated once they go out of scope. You must be very careful not to return any pointers to them once their function has returned.

On most contemporary architectures they will reside on the stack (unless the compiler puts them in registers). The allocation itself is very cheap as it only involves incrementing the stack pointer.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks! So, here only stack memory allocation comes into play as being an automatic variable . Got confused by the concept of dynamic memory allocation in 'struct' while learning about linked list data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Books` structure allocates, each time a book is instantiated (i.e. when you declare `Book1` and `Book2` in your `main` function) an array of 50 chars (50 bytes) that can be used to store the title.

To get a sense of how things work, try the same program with the following Books definition

```
struct Books {
    char * title
}
```